# CSGO Weapon Case Key Problems

Tags: steam, pc

So I bought CS GO from a 3rd party website to add to my steam account. It is the only steam game I have as I am not interested in any other games at the moment. I have received a case and was wanting to buy a key to open it, however it says my steam account is locked and I cannot buy any in game items. I have tried multiple websites but I either says my account is locked or I have to reach level 1 on steam! Could someone please help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you bought your keys on a 3rd party website that we cannot help troubleshoot for you.

Comment: I guess your account is "locked" because you have not bought any game on steam. If this is the case you shouldnt be able to add friends. To solve this you have to buy a game on steam.

Comment: Do you even have a credit card or wallet cash on your account?

Comment: @contrabandbandicoot, without understanding how steam works, it is easy to make this assumption. OP is asking about an item that has dropped in game. From what they have listed, it is a fair assumption that they are **already playing CS GO in steam**. All game keys do is give you access to the game. OPs problem does not stem from having purchased it from a 3rd party.

Answer (score 2):

From what I can see, Counter Strike: GO weapon keys are available through the Steam Marketplace.

**This is a different area to the Steam Store**

The Marketplace is a place for players to sell their dropped items. In order to have access to the Marketplace, you need to have purchased something directly from the Steam store.

Comment: Keys are also available ingame.